# How to find where my automapper mapping is used - find usages of mapping

Tags: automapper

I'm on a project with lots of Automapper mappings.
However, not all work great, or have too many responsibilities, so we want to edit some of them.

But when changing them, I first want to check where they are used.

**Is there a simple way to check where a mapping is used, sort of a 'find usages'?**

(I normally have the same issue the other way around, when I see Mapper.Map.... that I find it hard to figure out which mapping is used at that moment, but that's another issue)

Comment: Yes, they're called unit tests :)

Comment: haha, good point. There is however, it may come as a surprise (lol) code out there not as unit tested as you would like ;-)

Comment: I usually do it like is - pick a particular mapping, select in VS `Find All References` on destination type and see if there are any calls to mapper using this type as destination type. Do note that this method has limited applications. It will work as long as you provide destination type as a generic type parameter when mapping. It won't work when mapping to specific implementations of open generics mapping and if you are using mapper while providing types via `System.Type` parameter.

Comment: How automapper works with deep nested objects is opaque is the answer (as far as I am aware)